# CircleCI submodule repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the requested repository

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-submodules, circleci, circleci-2.0

In circleci, I get the following error when checking out a submodule

> Submodule 'submod' (git@bitbucket.org:xx/submod.git) registered for
>   path 'submod' Cloning into '/home/circleci/code/submod'... Warning:
>   Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx' to
>   the list of known hosts.
>
> repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the
>   requested repository. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists. fatal: clone of 'git@bitbucket.org:xx/submod.git' into
>   submodule path '/home/circleci/code/submod' failed Failed to clone
>   'submod'. Retry scheduled

my config.yml is

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-25-alpha
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: git submodule sync
      - run: git submodule update --init
      - run: echo "A second hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming those repositories being used as submodules are private? An SSH key needs to be created for those repos, and added to them (on GitHub) and to CircleCI.

Comment: could you elaborate? I tried this - generated a new sshkey, added the public key to GitHub under Deploy Keys, and the private key for CircleCI under sshkeys and still got permission denied.